# Enforce type of property values without override them in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an object that looks something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  say: {
    hello: speaker => {},
    hi: speaker => {}
  },
  write: {
    hello: (writer, pen) => {}
  }
};
```

Now if I type `obj.say.` it'll show me the `hello` and `hi` methods in the autocomplete, and the parameter name shows as `speaker`:

[image: typescript autocomplete]

I want to enforce a structure on the object properties, so I'm setting this type on `obj`:

```js
type ObjType =  {
  [action in "say" | "write"]: {
    [messageType: string]: (person: { name: string }, tool?: any) => void;
  }
}

const obj : ObjType = ...
```

But now, if I type `obj.say` it doesn't show the `hello` and `hi` options, and when I try to call the function it uses the definition from ObjType, rather than the more detailed type.

[image]

Can I somehow get the best of both worlds? For example, I want to enforce that the functions always have at least one argument, but it should use the argument name I specified in each function.

The best I could think of was to not set `ObjType` on `obj` but instead add an extra variable `let enforcerObj : ObjType = obj` that isn't used for anything except to cause a type error.

Comment: By saying `obj: ObjType`, you explicitly tell the compiler to treat `obj` as an `ObjType`, so the Intellisense for `obj.say.hi` is correct in your screenshot. What are you trying to achieve here? It sounds a bit like an XY problem.

Comment: @Rengers I want to force all `obj` members to match a type, without overriding their actual types.

Answer (score 0):

Done that for you:

```
const obj: ObjType = {
  say: {
    hello: (speaker) => {},
    hi: (speaker) => {},
  },
  write: {
    hello: (writer, pen) => {},
  },
};

type ActionsKeys = 'say' | 'write';
type GreetingsKeys = 'hi' | 'hello';
type ActionFunction = (person: string, tool?: any) => void;
type ObjType = {
  [a in ActionsKeys]: Partial<
    {
      [b in GreetingsKeys]: ActionFunction;
    }
  >;
};
```

[image]
[image]

It requires `strict` enabled in TS config.
It works well in VS Code:
[image]

however IntelliJ does not handle it well.

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue here is that it still loses the original type, e.g. it suggests the `hi` method for `obj.write`, even though that method doesn't exist.

Comment: EDIT: checked it. It will not compile when you are in `strict`. 
It works well in VS Code

Comment: As it is IntelliJ issue I have reported it to Jetbrains! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40691

Comment: I've been trying it in the TypeScript playground. The issue is that they're all optional now, even though obj.say.hello always exists. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAXDA8kgKgTwA4FMYBeGAbwCgYYIBDbVCqqgC3wBs2RUAKCAmgNb4ATgEpiAPjIBfADSUmzAJY8++QSPFEppOQr1UA7sKVR8DBS3acex0yNkwCYLToMw90gNzlyUPIQAgsBQSuAQANL42BDEMADktNjxMAA+CXZm8T7+BDAA4sL4+KFgAOaR0bEk8cop6bXWINl+ATDBoeAAYgCuYCFhYHHcBMIQ4KjQJuWOUCAgbAD8qDRg2K4wAG4gSgAmOW0YiDh5JIwwANo0MEpDHYOVMQC6qAAKNMKhNGwAPJZk-yoF3gNyGhWKpQqUWeqHu3T6A3APiYHgUEh83l8QA

Comment: I can adjust it if you want to stick to this type however I thought you want to make it dynamic